# Как извлечь информацию из раскодированного json?

Tags: php

Изначально искал по словам:`

```
$url = 'https://service.sovetromantica.com/v1/animesearch?anime_name='.preg_replace('/(\s+)/i', '%',($_GET["animename"]));;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$obj = json_decode($data, true);`
```

И таким образом все прекрасно выводилось:

```
<?php
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++):
                $id = ($i + 1);
                $ai = $id;
                $animeID = $obj[$ai]['anime_id'];
                $animename = $obj[$ai]['anime_name'];
                $animedescription = $obj[$ai]['anime_description'];
                $anime_keywords = $obj[$ai]['anime_keywords'];
                $anime_folder = $obj[$ai]['anime_folder'];

                $animeepisodes = $obj[$ai]['anime_episodes'];
                $animenamerussian = $obj[$ai]['anime_name_russian'];
                $animestudio = $obj[$ai]['anime_studio'];

                $animeyear = $obj[$ai]['anime_year'];
                $episodecurrentdub = $obj[$ai]['episode_current_dub'];
                $episodecurrentsub = $obj[$ai]['episode_current_sub'];
                
                $pagean = $anime_folder.'.php';

            ?>
```

Но поиск по ID не работает, я думал принцип тот же:

```
$url = 'https://service.sovetromantica.com/v1/anime/'.($_GET["animeID"]);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$obj = json_decode($data1, true);
```

var_dump выводит:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(15) { ["anime_description"]=> string(1812) "Жил-поживал один неприметный старшеклассник — горя не знал, рисовал рисульки разнообразные, в основном про рыцарей, которые прекрасных дам из беды выручают и героизмом, значит, поражают в самое сердце. Естественно, сам таковым ни разу не являлся, а лишь фантазии свои на бумагу переносил. Замкнутый, ранимый, мечтательный Сэмпай... Но манга мангой, а в реальной жизни всё иначе. Нагаторо [長瀞 早瀬], недавно переведённая в ту же школу, архетипичный образ девы в беде не разделяет. Воплощение зла, огнедышащее чудовище, скрывающееся под личиной миленькой девчушки, — вот кто она! И стоило только Сэмпаю с ней познакомиться, как жизнь его превратилась в ад. Ну что, скажите на милость, эта чертовка в нём нашла? И хотя Нагаторо изо дня в день продолжает терроризировать свою жертву, жертва-то, кажется, начинает привыкать. Но главное, она понимает, что даже у «чудовища» есть свои слабости. И кто знает, возможно, эта история расскажет о том, как неловкий рыцарь подружился со своим смертельным врагом..." ["anime_episodes"]=> int(0) ["anime_folder"]=> string(23) "ijiranaide-nagatoro-san" ["anime_id"]=> int(1221) ["anime_keywords"]=> string(180) "Ijiranaide, Nagatoro San, イジらないで、長瀞さん, Нагаторо, хватит издеваться!, Don't Toy with Me, Miss Nagatoro, Please don't bully me, Nagatoro" ["anime_name"]=> string(24) "Ijiranaide, Nagatoro-san" ["anime_name_russian"]=> string(41) "Не издевайся, Нагаторо" ["anime_ongoing"]=> int(1) ["anime_paused"]=> int(0) ["anime_shikimori"]=> int(42361) ["anime_soft_raw_link"]=> string(72) "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AKwdtgbxoTUwwcVM_A_nZmT4muxMzNZb" ["anime_studio"]=> int(0) ["anime_year"]=> int(2021) ["episode_current_dub"]=> int(1) ["episode_current_sub"]=> int(1) } }
```

То есть декодирует оно правильно, но извлечь нужную информацию я не могу.

Comment: Надо `$ai = $i;`. У вас же массив с нуля начинается, а не с 1. Либо `$id = $i;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я пробовал, ставил 0 и 1 место $ai

Comment: Кто вам запрещает извлечь нужную информацию?

Comment: а что мешаєт использовать foreach ?